ImportError: cannot import name 'send_event' from 'haystack.telemetry'
I have installed haystack like so:
pip install 'farm-haystack[all]' 
I work on ubuntu in Python 3.10.5.
When I run
import haystack
I get this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'send_event' from 'haystack.telemetry' 
So far, I was not able to find a solution to this error (could it be incompatibility with the Python version?), any advice would be greatly appreciated.

https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/issues/6652

This may be unrelated but be aware that farm-haystack (Haystack 1.x) and haystack-ai (Haystack 2.x) are not compatible (https://docs.haystack.deepset.ai/docs/get_started).

Try running pip uninstall haystack-ai and see if that resolves your issue

The deinstallation of farm-haystack and the installation of pip install haystack-ai worked for me!
